# How to target the mui paper component from select style without using the sx props?

Tags: css, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to style the Select MUI component using the styled function. Since I want to share this style later on, I don't want to keep using sx. I've tried a couple of approaches, but I am missing the right class to be able to target the Paper directly from within the styled function

```js
// Styled 
export const StyledSelect = styled(Select)<SelectProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  textAlign: 'start',
  margin: '5px',
  fontWeight: 800,
  
  '& .MuiSelect-select': {
    // List
    '& .MuiList-root': {
      color: 'green',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    // Paper 
    '& .MuiMenu-paper': {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  },
})

// Component
<FormControl>
  <StyledSelect
  variant={variant}
  labelId='select-label'
  // This works 100%
  // MenuProps={{
  //   PaperProps: {
  //     sx: {
  //       backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  //       backdropFilter: 'blur(10px)',
  //     },
  //   },
  // }}
  name={name}
  disabled={disabled}
  value={value}

  onChange={onChangeFn}
  displayEmpty
  >
  </StyledSelect>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MUI [`Paper`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-paper/) within a default [`Select`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) has always been a trickier to handle as a styled component because the `Paper` falls outside of the `Select`'s DOM hierarchy (due to it use of a [Portal](https://mui.com/base-ui/react-portal/)).  In order to style it (and the `Select`), you first need to style the `Select` and then use that styled `Select` as the base component from which to style the `Paper`.  For example:

```
const BaseSelect = styled(Select)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: "green", // Added just for the example
  textAlign: 'start',
  margin: '5px',
  fontWeight: 800,
}));

// To style the Menu Paper
const StyledSelect = styled(({ className, ...props }: SelectProps) => (
  <BaseSelect {...props} MenuProps={{ PaperProps: { className } }} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: "red", // Added just for the example
  // backgroundColor: "transparent",
  backdropFilter: "blur(10px)"
}));

...

// Use as you normally would
// <StyledSelect ... >
```

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-mui-select-and-paper-2dmpct?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: so this cannot be done by nesting classes in the baseSelect..

Comment: @Richardson No -- Not to my knowledge. This has been an issue with the Select's Portal usage since at least MUI 4.

Answer (score 1):

We have faced similar issues while using `styled-components` to target child classes to create a base component. Sometimes there are multiple child components you want to target. It's a bit tricky. You will face similar issues with components like `Autocomplete`, `DatePicker`, etc.
So we start using two different approaches.

✅1️⃣ **Create a base component using `sx` props:**

```
export const BaseSelect = (props: SelectProps) => {
    return (
       <Select
         {...props}
         sx={{
            bgcolor: 'green',
            ...props.sx, //spread your sx from props, so you can override these styles if needed
          }}
         MenuProps={{
            PaperProps: {
               sx: {
                  bgcolor: 'red', //sx for Paper
               },
             },
           }}
         />
      )}


//USAGE
<BaseSelect
     value={age}
     label="Age"
     sx={{
       height: 100, //You can still use sx and override base styling if needed
     }}
   >
```

✅2️⃣  **Create reusable `sx` variables:**

```
export const SELECT_BASE_SX: SxProps = {
  bgcolor: 'green',
}

export const PAPER_SX: SxProps = {
  bgcolor: 'red',
}

//USAGE
<Select
  sx={{
    ...SELECT_BASE_SX,
    height: 100,
  }}
  MenuProps={{
    PaperProps: {
      sx: {
        ...PAPER_SX,
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

I hope it helps.